# Techniques for evaluating hard limits

Tags: limits

Can anyone name some tools to evaluate hard problems on limits like Stolz Cesara theorem.
Are there any other techniques like that?

Comment: The best technique is probably to visit the tag "limits" as much as possible on MSE. That being said you can use very powerful tools like Taylor series, L'Hospital's Rule but often in practice the usual limit laws and a combination of well known limits suffices.

Comment: I agree with Paramanand.